# Alamofire gives error after pod install

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode8

I know that there is many questions about that but I can't find a solution for that. I use Xcode 8 and swift 2.3. When I add Alamofire in my application the build always fails and it gives me error in relation with the swift version. If anyone was facing the same issue and fixed it please give me the solution for than or advice me about the right way to use Alamofire without errors (it's the first time that I will use it and I'm really new to ios devlopement)

**Edit:**
I tested this: `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.5'`
then I did a `pod install` and when I build the project I got this error:

Alamofire will not be code signed because its settings don't specify a development team.
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

Comment: What version of Alamofire are you using?

Comment: I tested with the 4.0 and the 3.5 and it doesn't work

Comment: Edit your question and add your podfile and error description you're getting.

Comment: Btw, forget about 4.0 with Swift 2.3. You should use 3.5

Comment: @alexburtnik see my edit please

Comment: Everyone should be in Swift 3.0.... Enough time has gone by. Lets keep Swift a language that doesn't have libraries written in a crazy number of different versions as mucha s possible :)

Comment: @Llg Try to open your `project.pbxproj` file with text editor and search for `SWIFT_VERSION`. Can you find any value different from 2.3?

Comment: A stupid question please: where the .pbxproj is located?

Comment: It's inside your `*.xcodeproj`. Right click -> Show package contents -> project.pbxproj

Comment: @alexburtnik yes I found it and the SWIFT_VERSION has no value. SWIFT_VERSION = "";

Comment: Sorry there is one having no value and others having 3.0 value

Answer (score 1):

In your podfile specify that you wan to download the 2.3 version by pasting this at the end of you Pofile under everything else in there.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
           config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
   end
end
```

In the middle line you can see that the `SWIFT_VERSION` for the build settings is changed to be `2.3` specifically. Overall this is how your podfile should look like:

```
target 'YourApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Weatherly
  pod 'Alamofire'

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
           config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
   end
end
```

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

**It looks like you're not really using Swift 2.3.**

1. Go to  Build Settings section of your target's settings.
2. Search for `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` and set it to `YES` if you really want to use Swift 2.3
3. Clean and build.

**If that doesn't help, try the following:**

1. Open `project.pbxproj` file

You can find it in the *.xcodeproj: *Right click -> Show package contents -> project.pbxproj*)

2. Search for `SWIFT_VERSION`. If there is any other value except 2.3, set it manually. For example 
   `SWIFT_VERSION = 3.0;` -> `SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3;`
3. Clean and build again.

The reason for manual editing of `project.pbxproj` file is that sometimes Xcode doesn't update all values for `SWIFT_VERSION` key. Faced this issue on 8.0, perhaps it was already fixed in 8.1

Comment: Have I to do that before or after the pod install? And also excuse me but yes I'm confusing between swift 3.0 and the 2.3 one. How can I be sure of version that I'm using? Is the value 3.0 means that I use the 3.0 in my code? Or it displayed the 3.0 because I have the Xcode 8? Note that I want that my min target be the 8 one

Comment: The order doesn't matter. But the version of Alamofire does. Basically `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` setting means that your project is using Swift 2.3. And if so, your libraries should also be written in Swift 2.3, in case of Alamofire it is 3.5.

Comment: I tested the two options but I got the same error. Before I set the SWIFT_VERSION manually I found that some of them become 2.3 and other 3.0. I set the whole to the 2.3 after that the clean and the build failed. And I got a lot of errors in my code like "UIScreen has no member main", "use of undeclared URL"...

Comment: `UIScreen.main` is a Swift 3.0 code. Where is it located? Your code or third party module?

Comment: Then your question is misleading. You tell us you're using 2.3 while you're not. You should make your choice between 2.3 and 3.0 and stick to it accross the whole app (including pods).

Comment: Excuse me it's because I'm really new to that. I'm really lost! I think that I'm confusing between the two versions in the same project. Does the swift 3 run in the 8 target?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128103/discussion-between-alexburtnik-and-llg).